# Built in potential of a pin diode?

Tags: diodes, pins

I'm not sure how the addition of the intrinsic region affects the built in potential of the diode. I also can't seem to find any information about it online. Thanks for the help.

How does the built in potential of a pin diode compare to a pn diode?

Comment: So what exactly is your question? _Edit the question_ and don't post the question in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The PIN diode will have the same barrier for the material; however, it will have a different frequency behavior.  The N and the P regions are highly doped, take a standard band diagram and then stretch it out.  The barrier height will be the the same.

I have used these devices as attenuators, and the low frequency behavior is identical, but at high frequency, they look much like a resistor.

I believe that there is a write up on them Andy Grove's "Physics and Technology of Semiconductor Devices"; however, I have not seen them described in detail anywhere else.